# moving box2d bodies in an arc or curved path

Tags: physics, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

How can I make a b2Body move in a arc-like or curved path? I have heard about cocos2d Bezier curve function (ccBezier) but this is for moving cocos2d sprites. Or can it be modified to move box2d bodies? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Why not just model a parabola and apply the necessary force? You get such an effect coming out of a cannon (arc).

Comment: @VaughanHilts: I am not sure how to model a parabola

Comment: Give your world a somewhat realistic gravity force. Then just apply an impulse at some angle. Box2D models real world physics and you're projectile will travel in a parabola just like real life.

Answer (score 1):

For box2d with gravity enabled, if you apply force to an object in the upwards direction, you will automatically get a parabolic trajectory.

Create a b2vec2 and apply that as the force to your body.

If you want to move the body or sprite manually, then use parabolic formulas to calculate your position in your update method.

Comment: Good answer, but it is highly NOT recommended to move the body manually. Just thought it was worth mentioning :)

Comment: Thanks, yes I agree.  Tried it once and updates were jittery.